# Why has a gravitational wave spin 2? (Group theoretically?)

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-spin, representation-theory, gravitational-waves

How can I see, using group theoretic arguments, that a the quantum of a gravitational wave has spin 2?

How can one show that it is described by a 5 dimensional representation of $SO(3)$?

I know the argument from Carroll's book on General Relativity: from looking at the perturbation on the geodesics followed by a perfect fluid, which are invariant under 180 degrees. But that doesn't seems very convincing.

Comment: First of all, you are wrong, the graviton has two degrees of freedom, not five and it is about $so(2)$ rather than $so(3)$. One linearizes Einstein equations and after imposing various gauges one finds $\square f_{ab}=0$, $\partial^c f_{ac}=0$ $\eta^{ab} f_{ab}=0$ and $f_{ab}\sim f_{ab}+\partial_a\xi_b+\partial_b\xi_a$, where $f_{ab}$ is the metric perturbation. Solving it by Fourier transform and  using the gauge symmetry you get two degrees of freedom and find that they belong to $so(2)$ representation. That $f_{ab}$ is a rank-two tensor already points towards spin-two

Comment: Firstly, it's not a representation of $SO(3)$ but of $SO(4)$. One would naively expect $2s+1 = 5$ independent degrees of freedom represented by a symmetric $g_{\mu \nu}$, just as one would expect $3$ degrees of freedom for a vector boson represented by an antisymmetric $F_{\mu\nu}$. However, gauge invariance implies that the vector boson has only 2 (on-shell) degrees of freedom i.e. 2 polarizations. Similarly, a graviton also has only 2 polarizations. For equations, refer to John's comment.

Comment: Intuitively, you can think of the 5 possible d-orbitals but drop the ones involving 'z' if your graviton is travelling in the z-direction. That leaves the $+$ and $\times$ polarizations as denoted conventionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should read Lightman, A. P., Press, W. H., Price, R. H., Teukolsky, S. A. , 1975: ``Problem 12.16''. Problem book in Relativity and Gravitation. Princeton University Press. ISBN 0-691-08162-X.